# saveAll($data) having issues

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am trying to add a new user using the below code in my `UsersControll.php`. The appropriate code is placed in all other associate files.

```
if ($this->User) {
    // because we like to send pretty mail
    // Set view variables as normal
    $this->set('userDetails', $data['User']);

    if ($this->User->saveAll($data)){

        $this->Session->setFlash('User added successfully', 'default', array('class' => 'errMsgLogin'));
        $this->redirect('manageUsers');
    } else {
        echo "not done";
    }
} else {
    // do nothing
}
```

I tested each module of code and am only having an issue in this section:-

```
if ($this->User->saveAll($data))
```

Can someone explain is `saveAll($data)` correct?

Code is not going into this section:(Means condition is not getting satisfied).

```
 if ($this->User->saveAll($data)){

        $this->Session->setFlash('User added successfully', 'default', array('class' => 'errMsgLogin'));
        $this->redirect('manageUsers');
    } else {
        echo "not done";
    }
```

Comment: `am only having an issue in this section` - what issue? Also please indent your code.

Comment: You've not stated what issue you're having or where `$data` is coming from. It would be useful if you showed what `$data` looks like.

Comment: Means condition is not getting satisfied... Entered some more details in question